# WCF transaction rollback while using two services to update two different databases - one being SQL data and other being Couchbase data

Tags: sql, wcf, transactions, couchbase, rollback

How to implement rollback database updates using WCF service, when I am using two different services to update two different databases - one being SQL data and other being Couchbase data?

Code as below:

```
            My web.config looks like this:
            Web.Config:

            <system.serviceModel>
                <diagnostics>
                  <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
                </diagnostics>
                <behaviors>
                  <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="TransactionBehavior">
                      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
                      set the values below to false before deployment -->
                      <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />-->
                      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
                      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
                      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
                      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
                    </behavior>
                  </serviceBehaviors>
                  <endpointBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="ImpersonationBehavior">
                      <clientCredentials>
                        <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" />
                      </clientCredentials>
                    </behavior>
                  </endpointBehaviors>
                </behaviors>

                <bindings>
                  <wsHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="wsHttpTransactionBinding" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
                      <!--<reliableSession enabled="false" />-->
                      <security mode="None" />
                    </binding>
                  </wsHttpBinding>
                </bindings>

                <services>
                  <service behaviorConfiguration="TransactionBehavior" name="BankingService.AccountService">
                    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpTransactionBinding" name="wsHttpEndPoint" contract="SharedLib.IAccountService" />
                  </service>
                </services>
                <!--Fix could not activate service error-->
                <serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
                  <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment>-->
                  <serviceActivations>
                    <add relativeAddress="AccountService.svc" service="BankingService.AccountService" factory="WebApp.UnityServiceHostFactory, WebApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                  </serviceActivations>
                </serviceHostingEnvironment>
                <client>
                  <endpoint address="http://localhost:9003/AccountService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ImpersonationBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpTransactionBinding" contract="SharedLib.IAccountService" name="wsHttpEndPoint" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
                </client>
             </system.serviceModel>


            App.config:

            <system.serviceModel>
                <bindings>
                  <wsHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="wsHttpTransactionBinding" transactionFlow="true" openTimeout="00:10:00" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
                       <security mode="None">
                      </security>
                    </binding>
                  </wsHttpBinding>
                  <netTcpBinding>
                    <binding name="netTcpTransactionBinding" transactionFlow="true" sendTimeout="00:20:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                      <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                      </security>
                    </binding>
                  </netTcpBinding>
                </bindings>
                <behaviors>
                  <endpointBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="ImpersonationBehavior">
                      <clientCredentials>
                        <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" />
                      </clientCredentials>
                    </behavior>
                  </endpointBehaviors>
                </behaviors>
                <client>
                  <endpoint address="http://localhost:9003/AccountService.svc"
                    behaviorConfiguration="ImpersonationBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="wsHttpTransactionBinding" contract="SharedLib.IAccountService"
                    name="wsHttpEndPoint" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
                </client>
            </system.serviceModel>

            ServiceContract is as below:
            IAccountService.cs

            [ServiceContract]    
            public interface IAccountService
            {
                [OperationContract]
                Task<IEnumerable<Account>> GetAccounts();

                [OperationContract, TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
                Task<bool> Debit(int accountID, int amount);

                [OperationContract, TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
                Task<bool> Credit(int accountID, int amount);

                [OperationContract]
                Task<int> GetBalance(int accountID);

                [OperationContract]
                Task<MiniStatement> GetMiniStatement(int accountID);
            }

            Service Implementation is as below:
            Account.cs

            [ServiceBehavior(
            TransactionIsolationLevel =
            System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = false)]   
            public class AccountService : IAccountService
            {
                BankRepository bankRepository = new BankRepository();
                CouchbaseRepository couchbaseRepository = new CouchbaseRepository();

                public AccountService()
                {
                }

                [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
                public Task<bool> Credit(int accountID, int amount)
                {
                    var creditAccountTask = Task.Run(async () =>
                       {
                           return await bankRepository.CreditAccount(accountID, amount, Transaction.Current);
                       });
                    var result = creditAccountTask.ContinueWith(async (t) =>
                      {
                          return t.Result != null ? await couchbaseRepository.CreditAccount(accountID, t.Result) : false;
                      }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
                    return result.Result;
                }

                [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
                public Task<bool> Debit(int accountID, int amount)
                {
                    var debitAccountTask = Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        return await bankRepository.DebitAccount(accountID, amount, Transaction.Current);
                    });
                    var result = debitAccountTask.ContinueWith(async (t) =>
                        {
                            return t.Result != null ? await couchbaseRepository.DebitAccount(accountID, t.Result) : false;
                        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
                    return result.Result;
                }

                public Task<IEnumerable<Account>> GetAccounts()
                {
                    return bankRepository.GetAccounts();
                }

                public Task<int> GetBalance(int accountID)
                {
                    return bankRepository.GetBalanceByAccountID(accountID);
                }

                public Task<MiniStatement> GetMiniStatement(int accountID)
                {
                    return couchbaseRepository.GetTransactionStatement(accountID);
                }

            }
```

The transactions still don't work when I use EF to save changes. Transaction.Current still comes as null.

Comment: you will require a distributed transaction coordinator

Comment: I have used that. Related question would be where do I enabled MSDTC? I have  a client, services hosted in another box and SQL server and couchbase database hosted in separate servers. I definitely cant be enabling the MSDTC on the client machine since ours is a desktop app and we use ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: Please have a look on this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60539259/multiple-documents-update-in-couchbase/62169212#62169212

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable Transaction Flow in your service bindings.
2. Enable Allow Transaction Flow on your operation contracts.
3. Create Transaction from client and call both services in the same transaction.

Check out this [blog post](https://thesaadworld.wordpress.com/2018/05/06/transactions-with-wcf-sessions/) explaining transactions and how you can enable them. I hope that you will find your answer.

Comment: The problem is since I am using entity framework, it creates its own transaction and hence any update I do in the first operation, it gets committed. So even if the second update operation fails and I rollback, the initial changes don't get rolled back. However the same thing if I try by executing SQL queries instead of EF, the rollback works.

Comment: How exactly are you creating EF transaction? If you're not explicitly creating the transaction on EF then it should already join your existing transaction. Asynchronous functions also don't inherit the existing transaction unless you enable the Async Flow option while creating transaction.

Comment: I create a transition scope from the client, and from which I call my services which in turn call the repository classes to update the DB. Since I use EF, the transactions get committed without a fuss. But then when I do a rollback from my client, it doesn't work. But if I use EF with queries something like this - context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, sqlQuery);
the rollback works fine

Comment: Seems like your repository classes are creating new independent transactions for database operations. Without seeing the actual code, I can only suggest you to make sure that your EF operations are performed on the same transaction as of client or service.

Comment: Here goes the sample code below, pretty simple(basic):
var account = await context.Account.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.AccountID == accountID);
account.Balance += amount;
context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;
await context.SaveChangesAsync();

Seems like EF creates its own transaction, not sure why it doesn't when I use queries like this using EF:
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, sqlQuery);

Comment: Ok, first try to wrap this code in a new transaction like `var transaction = new TransactionScope(Transaction.Current, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled){ //write EF code here}` this will ensure that you EF code is called in your existing transaction. Also, update your question with complete code to make it clear for future audience.

Comment: Tried this, but the Transaction.Current is coming as null. If I try to pass it around from where I create in the client to the services, it throws an exception which goes like this "The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:currentTransaction"

Comment: What do you mean by pass it around? are you passing it as data member? it won't serialize this way. Your client transaction is not flowing to service, that is why Transaction.Current is null at the service end. Just make sure that your bindings and transaction flow attributes are in place as explained in my article.

Comment: I have added code snippet. I am not passing Transactions as that cant be serialized. Apart from not implementing callbacks, everything else remains same.